# Can HR in company B tell HR in company A about me?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, human-resources

I have accepted a job offer at company A, then went to interview at company B and informed them about my acceptance of the offer at company A.

Company B said they can't continue with the application process because of that.

I figured out how stupid I was after all of that happened so you don't have to scold me about that.

Now I'm starting to worry that HR in company B would tell HR in company A about me. Is there a risk of this happening?

Comment: Locale and/or company specific, voting to close as off topic

Comment: This sounds more like, "Why won't Company B talk to me after I've accepted Company A's offer?"

Comment: @Makoto No this is not my question, I understand why company B doesn't want to talk to me now.

My question is: is there a risk that company B would tell company A about what happened.

Comment: The true answer is "it depends", notably on whether or not Company A has non-compete clauses in its employment agreement, or other locale-specific concerns.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with interviewing at other companies especially during the very limited amount of time you have between jobs. Company B likely does not want to get accused of "poaching" by Company A, that's their prerogative but not all employers would feel the same. As for B talking to A, there is nothing to prevent that. The HR people might know each other and people are free to chat (regardless of what any laws say). I would not worry too much. If you're asked about it, just explain you wanted to take an opportunity to explore options with B. Not a big deal.

Comment: You basically told company B you were not interested in any offer they might have had by saying you had already accepted an offer

Comment: @Ramhound yup I'm stupid.

Comment: Until you sign the papers to start your job, they can withdraw their offer, even after that until your actually at your desk they could withdraw their offer in theory.  Just a matter if it's worth their time to do so

Comment: Even if B told A about you, what bad thing could happen? B: "Hi there, buba told us that he accepted your job offer." A: "Yes, he did."

Answer (score 2):

In most companies, HR's primary role is to reduce risk. And outside of Accounting, they are probably subject to the highest regulatory and compliance burden on the org chart. In the scenario you've described, it's incredibly unlikely that Company B would contact Company A, as it could only *increase* risk and exposure.

Comment: HR also owes you a duty of confidentiality.